# how to dynamically solve this random-button-implementation

Tags: java, android, dynamically-generated

I am having a list with the integers 0,1,2,3,4. then I am shuffling it, and as the third step I want to initialize the Buttons with the first object related to button1, second object to button2 etc.
It works if I do it manually, but I want to solve it dynamically.

```
    List<Integer> objects = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            objects.add(0);
            objects.add(1);
            objects.add(2);
            objects.add(3);
            objects.add(4);

        // Shuffle the collection
    Collections.shuffle(objects);

//this is not working here, but it should reflect what i am trying to achieve here
// -->
    for (int i = 0; i<objects.size(); i++) {
        Button button**i** = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button**i**);
        button**i**.setText(objects.get(i).toString());
    }
```

Thanks in advance. Any help appreciated (poking my nose in the right direction)

Comment: what is not working? are you getting error at `R.id.button**i**`?

Comment: well, you cant stringbuild a variable variablename on its initialization within java.

Comment: java does not allow that. you can use the approach @fonZ answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this by shuffling your button list. As you are iterating with an int, it can serve as index for the shuffled list.

Like this:

```
List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.button0));
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.button1));
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.button2));
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.button3));
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.button4));

Collections.shuffle(buttons);

for (int i = 0, s = 4; i < s; i++) {
    buttons.get(i).setText("" + i);
}
```

Comment: "at"-method undefined for List<Button>. should be "get". and i really like your idea!

Comment: Worth noting the first line can be simplified to `List<Integer> indexes = Arrays.asList(new int[] {0,1,2,3,4});`

Comment: @Duncan Jones i made it simple to read, as he was using a list. I used a list to avoid confusion. But if you read well i state that you can either use a list or an array.

Comment: @fonZ Read my comment carefully. I was just suggesting a quicker way to populate the list. But yes, your newer solution is simpler.